# Batch compare timer result to a number

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch timer (saw it in a different stackOverFlow post) and I need to compare the elapsed time to a number in order to know when 10 seconds are pass, however, I'm getting an error when trying to compare the two.
What am I doing wrong?

```
@set /A _tic=%time:~0,2%*3600^
            +%time:~3,1%*10*60^
            +%time:~4,1%*60^
            +%time:~6,1%*10^
            +%time:~7,1% >nul



echo RUN-KILL-WATCHDOG-THE-SMART-WAY

SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
set EXE=python.exe

:RUNNERON
FOR /F "skip=1" %%x IN ('wmic process where "CommandLine Like '%%forking import main%%' and Caption='python.exe'" get caption') DO for /F "delims=" %%j in ("%%x") do (
    echo The name of process who passed filter is: %%j Waiting for it to terminate...
    IF %%j == %EXE% (
        :: TOK
        set /A _toc=%time:~0,2%*3600^
                +%time:~3,1%*10*60^
                +%time:~4,1%*60^
                +%time:~6,1%*10^
                +%time:~7,1% >nul
        set /A _elapsed=%_toc%-%_tic
        :: echo %_elapsed% seconds.
        IF %_elapsed%==10 goto TIMEOUT :: EVERYTHING WORKS BUT THIS LINE
        goto RUNNERON
    ) ELSE (
        echo Entered "else" part - something went wrong.
    )
)
echo Runner is done - killing watchdog process
taskkill /F /im "python.exe"

: TIMEOUT
echo TIMEOUT

pause
```

when I run it I get the error:
"goto was unexpected at this time."

What am I missing?
Thank you

Comment: 1/ Don't use `::`-style comments within a code block (parenthesised series of lines) use `rem` statements instead. `::` is a misused label and labels are not allowed in code blocks. 2/ refer to articles about `delayedexpansion` using the search facility in the top bar. Succinctly, `%var% means the value of the variable at the time the outermost `for` is encountered; hence `_elapsed` is empty, hence the `if %_...` is interpreted as `if ==10 goto...` which is a syntax violation.

Comment: @Magoo Thank you, I removed the `::` and understood the error. SLOVED it by taking the entire TOK part outside the for loops. Thanks

Comment: 1/ A `set /a` doesn't require `%` - it works on the current value of the variable "nude". 2/ append `enabledelayedexpansion` to the `setlocal` command (`enableextensions` is on by default) and then replace any `%var%` that you want to use by `!var!` which accesses the run-time value of the variable whereas `%var%` is the value when the entire `for` loop was parsed. Note also that a variable reference for an ordinary environment variable (like `time`) is (eg) `%time:~6,1%*10%` - you are missing the ending `%` (many times). Also, `^` to concatenate lines is valid but rarely used.